# Python - Insert in database table

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have a variable and I want to insert its value into my database table. I have this but that doesn't work:

```
import mysql.connector
import statistics
idk = []
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  database="python"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT `First Name` FROM employees")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
    idk.append(x)

y = statistics.mode(idk)
f = '( ,)'.join(y)

print(f)

mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO results (`First Name`) VALUES (%s)", f)

mydb.commit()
```

And I get this error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1

Comment: Normally the execute function required you to pass a sequence of parameters, e.g. `[f]` rather than `f`. It doesn't seem like that should cause an SQL syntax error though.

Comment: `VALUES (%s)` should be `VALUES ('%s')`

Comment: @Kaushal No it shouldn't.

Comment: `'( ,)'.join(y)` isn't doing what you think.  Try printing it to see.

Comment: @JohnGordon I would have said the same, but they already are printing it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have already found the answer. I just needed to type f in [].

```
import mysql.connector
import statistics
idk = []
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  database="python"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT `First Name` FROM employees")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
    idk.append(x)

y = statistics.mode(idk)
f = '( ,)'.join(y)

print(f)

mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO results (`First Name`) VALUES (%s)", [f])

mydb.commit()
```